# Symbolic link from Nas to home folder

Tags: networking, symbolic-link, drive, nas

I'm trying to create a link from my unraid Nas to my Ubuntu vm that I have running in it but ever time I make it the link says its broken and wants me to remove it

Comment: You've provided few details, what release are you using? (inc. desktop? server? other?) what protocol? (NFS?, SaMBa? or other?) how are you mounting it?  (file-system table entry? or other?) etc.

Comment: symlinks need to be on the same partition. You need to first have to mount the NAS to your local filesystem.